# Image in "html/text" Andrioid webview? without any html file

Tags: android, webview, assets

I want to Add On-receive error when ever site not reached or at offline

So here its working fine.... Here I want to add a image

But Image is not showing form assets folder

This is my Code

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Callback extends WebViewClient{
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){

        String html = "<div><p>&nbsp;<img style=\"display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\" src=\"file:///android_asset/img/error.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"218\" height=\"218\" /></p></div><div><p style=\"color: black; font-size: 20px; text-align: left;\"><strong><span style=\"color: #808080;\">Oops, Unable to load information.</span></strong></p><div style=\"color: black; text-align: center;\"><span style=\"color: #ff99cc;\"><strong>Please check your Network connection.</strong></span></div><br /><div><p style=\"color: black; text-align: center;\"><strong>Or</strong><br /><br /></p><div style=\"color: black; text-align: center;\"><span style=\"color: #666699;\"><strong>Server May be Temporarily Down</strong></span></div><div style=\"color: black; text-align: center;\"><div style=\"color: black; text-align: center;\"><span style=\"color: #666699;\"><strong>Please Try After Sometime</strong></span></div></div></div></div>";

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");

    }
}
```

Comment: \"file:///android_asset/img/error.png\\\" why do you need an extra '\' after the file name?

Comment: Yes without that is showing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code it is working for me,

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,html, "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
```